# Requesting help with designing curriculum (Logic)

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am currently a math major in university who wants to design my own area of study/major, specifically in Logic. I was wondering if I could get some help on how Logic sets itself apart from philosophy?

To be very honest, I don't like any of the history of philosophy and epistemology courses. Logic courses (modal, inductive, and paradoxes) are fun and they tie in well with my math major. But I can't say that in my proposal.

Requesting help regarding why Logic is so different from other philosophy branches and how a math student could benefit from choosing this major.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are mostly interested in mathematical logic, which is not part of philosophy although it is used in philosophy. You probably shouldn't reinvent the wheel and use an existing text, e.g. [Philosophical Logic by Burgess](https://books.google.it/books?id=k32w3_wjBoYC&hl=it&source=gbs_navlinks_s) is relatively math-heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Smith's authoritative study guide *Teach Yourself Logic* at https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/ is a very nice favour. It presents a handy map of the whole field of mathematical logic. Going over the text, you may collect helpful ideas for your proposal.