# Philosophy books with mathematical and logical notation

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for some philosophy books that employ a technical notation, similar to math and logic books. I do not care too much about the subject matter of the books, just books that employ formal logical notation.

Comment: Books recommended in this [recent thread](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/75562/9148) meet the requirement. But this is done only for a very narrow range of philosophical topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hartry Field, Saving Truth from Paradox (OUP, 2008)

David Lewis, Counterfactuals (Blackwell, 1973)

Judea Pearl, Causality (CUP, 2nd ed, 2009)

Ian Rumfitt, Boundary Stones of Thought (OUP, 2015)

Timothy Williamson, Modal Logic as Metaphysics (OUP, 2013)

Comment: Science seeks for _empirical truths_, philosophy for _final truths_. Judea Pearl's book is completely focused on science and empirical facts. I would hardly consider it a philosophy book.

Comment: For myself, I wouldn't say there is a clear dividing line between science and philosophy. If a philosophical dispute can be settled by appealing to empirical information, so much the better. Causation is a subject that has long been of interest to philosophers and there is a huge literature on it, e.g. John Mackie's The Cement of the Universe and James Woodward's Making Things Happen. Pearl's book is a major contribution to our understanding of the logic of causal relationships and would be of interest to any philosopher studying causation.

Answer (score 1):

Graham Priest's *[One](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/one-9780199688258?cc=us&lang=en&)* and *[Towards Non-Being](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/towards-non-being-9780198783602?cc=us&lang=en&)* employ formal logic notation, while engaging in deep philosophical questions.

David Kaplan's *[Demonstratives](https://philpapers.org/rec/KAPD)* while not a book, is long enough to be, and also involves a lot of logic notation.